# find $T$ so that $T \oplus W = M_{2 \times 3}(\mathbb R)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Given
> $$ W = \operatorname{span}\left\{\pmatrix{1&1&1\\ 1&2&3}, \pmatrix{1&0&1\\2&2&3}\right\},$$
> Find $T$ so that $M_{2\times 3}(\mathbb R) = W \oplus T$.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: @Spectre thanks for the edit! do you know by any chance how can I make a matrix ? didn't find in in the MathJax docs ((111),(101) and (123),(223) are  actully single 2*3 metrix)

Comment: @Spectre By removing the "sp," you changed the nature of the question. Please be more careful with future edits.

Comment: Please give us some context for this question. I would guess that this is from a course you are taking or textbook that you are reading, and you have already looked at similar questions. If this is the case, then what is it about this problem that you find particularly confusing? If not, then how did you come across this problem, and what are your thoughts on how to approach it?

Comment: Oh sorry, @BenGrossmann....I am a teen and I gain points mostly by editing (just because I am not acquainted with high-level math) , so sorry for the error - I didn't know what that "sp" meant.......

Comment: @Ben Grossmann your guess would be correct. This is part of a course. But the thing that confusing about it is that A) I have not encountered such a problem from that type yet and B) there is no theorem / method that can assist me from what I can see. I even have a solution: use {e1,1-e2,3} and then eliminate the two e-s that can be expressed with liner combinations. but this method is so non- elegant and non math-ish that I rather not to use it.

Comment: @avivgood2 I'm not sure what you mean by "use {e1,1-e2,3}". When you say that you have not encountered such a problem, do you mean that you have not encountered problems about the span of a set? Have you not encountered problems about the direct sum $\oplus$? I strongly suspect that the thing you find confusing about this problem is merely the fact that our sets have matrices as opposed to column-vectors. If not, then please point out the specific aspects of the question that make it confusing.

Comment: @BenGrossmann column-vectors questions are easier to solve, obviously,  but my issues with this specific is the part of finding the direct sum that result in X, rather then the one I usually solve which is from time "prove that this and that is direct sum" (and en,m is: the zero matrix except that the n,m cell of it is one)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a hint to one approach:

**Sketch of Solution:** It suffices to find a basis of the nullspace of the matrix
$$
A = 
\pmatrix{1&1&1 & 1&2&3\\
1&0&1&2&2&3},
$$
whose rows are formed from the "vectorized" versions of the given matrices. Once we have a basis $w_1,w_2,w_3,w_4$ of this nullspace, we find that the vectors $v_1,v_2,w_1,w_2,w_3,w_4$ form a basis of $\Bbb R^6$. It follows that when we "unvectorize" these vectors, we get a basis of $\Bbb R^{2 \times 3}$.

The unvectorized versions of $w_1,\dots,w_4$ will form a basis of a space $T$ for which $\Bbb R^{2\times 3} = W \oplus T$.